# Is the failure of the Restart, Power Off, Shut down Buttons in Ubuntu 21.10 a bug or a HW problem?

Tags: shutdown, restart

-Computer- Acer Aspire
Processor       : AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G
Memory      : 11175MB (1802MB used)
Machine Type        : Desktop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 21.10
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm:3

Click any of the aforementioned buttons, the shutdown screen disappears, nothing happens on the computerand a blank screen shows no connection. To shut down, have to use the power button on the computer.

Comment: Don't press and hold the power button. See [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Press the Up Arrow button on your keyboard after clicking the Restart or Shutdown button. This should show some messages on your screen. Copy down the last few lines and any lines that says Errors etc. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1380156/edit) and add these lines. Format the added lines as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Kernel, the default kernel for ubuntu `21.10` at the time of writing should be `5.13.0-20-generic`.

Use the following command to check

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-20-generic
```

Let’s update the system first so that all repositories are up to date. To update the system we used the following command.

`$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

After the process is complete we can now download the Linux kernel headers from Ubuntu kernel mainline page. Use the following code to accomplish that:

```
$ wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc7/amd64/linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_all.deb
```

```
$ wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc7/amd64/linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_all.deb

--2021-11-01 10:58:10--  https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc7/amd64/linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_all.deb
Resolving kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.216
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12189104 (12M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_all.deb’

linux-headers-5.15.0-051500r 100%[===========================================>]  11.62M  16.1MB/s    in 0.7s    

2021-11-01 10:58:11 (16.1 MB/s) - ‘linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_all.deb’ saved [12189104/12189104]
```

- wget: this is used to retrieved content from the website.
- wget -c: instruct the system to continue downloading partially downloaded images.

Next, we can download Linux Generic headers with the following command.

```
$ wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc7/amd64/linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_amd64.deb
```

When this is complete we can now download Linux kernel image from the following:

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc7/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_amd64.deb
```

Lastly, we can download the modules required to build the kernel.

```
$ wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc7/amd64/linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_amd64.deb
```

Install new kernel now with the following command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic.
(Reading database ... 62253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7 (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic_5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7 (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
Setting up linux-modules-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic (5.15.0-051500rc7.202110251930) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-20-generic
done
```

After installation is complete we can reboot the system for the new changes to take effect.

`$ sudo shutdown -r now`

Now you can check the version of the Linux kernel you are running again to see if we are successful with our installation

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-051500rc7-generic
```

The above solved the shutdown bug for me, i hope it solves yours too.

**Stay Safe!!**

Comment: Do you have a Ryzen 5 processor?

Comment: @Abhirikshma am using Ryzen 7, but the fix also works with Ryzen 5

Comment: Ya, I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 21.10 (Ryzen 5) and it got fixed with a kernel update from 5.13.0-27 to 5.13.0-28, right from the built-in Software Updater.